# Stylesheet preference in case of multiple css files in Angular 8

Tags: css, angular

I have multiple CSS stylesheets for angular components in my project. I was wondering if there is a way of setting a preferred stylesheet in case multiple sheets loaded by a component have same styles with different values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS rules are applied in the order they appear in the stylesheet and in the order the stylesheets are called. Those which come later (also in stylesheets which are loaded later) will overwrite earlier ones if the selector is exactly the same or has a higher *specificity*.